# What do characters like "drwx--xr-x" mean in the output of "ls"?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Can someone explain to me what the `drwx...` lines mean? As I understood starting with `d` is directory and with `-` (dash) is a normal file. Can someone confirm and help me understand what files I should create? I am so sorry if this wastes your time but I really got stuck.

[image: the question part is in red rectangle]

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about **writing software**, not using software or standard tools. This question should be at our sister site [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/171858/how-do-i-interpret-the-results-of-the-ls-l-command) on Super User.

Comment: I'm trying to write software - and this was what I was thinking

Comment: Did you consider consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These show you the file permissions, as can bee seen in nearly any unix system represented this way. The first character tells you if it is a directory (marked as ‚d‘), then you continue in groups of three for read (‚r‘), write (‚w’) and execute (‚x’) permissions for the owning user, group and everyone else.

In your example, the second entry is no directory (first position is ´-´), the owning user, which is ‚login‘, has read write and execute permissions. The owning group is ‚wheel‘ and can only execute, however everyone can read.

As this is basic stuff, you can find plenty of information about file permissions on unix/linux/whatever on the net.

IMHO the Arch-Wiki has a good overview for beginners:

[Arch Wiki - File permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions)

Comment: @dfuchs, in the future, note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, and therein the bullet point regarding questions which "are not about programming as [defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". Behind that link, note that "unique to software development" is ANDed into other conditions, making it necessary rather than sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

`[-bcdlpsw][-r][-w][-Ssx][-r][-w][-Ssx][-r][-w][-Ttx]`
is a regular expression for ls-encoded mode bits, at least on BSD & macOS.
See the [`ls`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls), [`lstat`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lstat), [`chmod`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod) and maybe[`xattr`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xattr.1.html) manual pages for details.  *Note ls-encoding looks a lot like the `stat.st_mode` bits printed in binary.*

```
[-bcdlpsw] is the file type, one of
    -   Regular file (here x = execute)
    b   Block special device
    c   Character special device
    d   Directory (here x = search)
    l   Symbolic link
    p   FIFO
    s   Socket
    w   Whiteout (pay no attention to the node behind the overlay/union)
[-r] User (owner) read access
[-w] User (owner) write access
[-Ssx] is one of
    -   User is denied execute/search access
    S   User is denied execute/search access and file is set-user-id
    s   User is granted execute/search access and file is set-user-id
    x   User is granted execute/search access
[-r] Group read access
[-w] Group write access
[-Ssx] is one of
    -   Group members are denied execute/search access
    S   Group members are denied execute/search access and file is set-group-id
    s   Group members are granted execute/search access and file is set-group-id
    x   Group members are granted execute/search access
[-r] Others read access
[-w] Others write access
[-Ttx] is one of
    -   Others are denied execute/search access
    T   Others are denied execute/search access and file is sticky
    t   Others are granted execute/search access and file is sticky
    x   Others are granted execute/search access
[+@] is optional under macOS, one of
    +   File has an Access Control List (ACL) or similar
    @   File has Extended Attributes (see the xattr command)
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like permission groups and types for files in Linux or Unix or OSX, more:
https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions